# Linux tar - just create the .snar file

Tags: linux, archive, tar

```
tar -zcpf backup.tar.gz -g files.snar /path/to/folder
```

creates a compressed archive of all the files under /path/to/folder.  No issues there.  However, I have no particular use for the backup.tar.gz file once I have the files.snar file.

How do I get tar to simply create files.snar and not the actual .gz file?  Sure I can delete it later but it sounds like an unnecessary operation. I have attempted to play around with /dev/null but my knowledge of how it works is rather limited.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/updating-tar-gz-daily-only-with-changed-files

Comment: To my downvoters - what is the point in downvoting if you do not indicate what is wrong with the question?  It was clear enough - I wanted the .snar without the actual archive.  Either you knew the answer or you did not. -1'ing a question without commentary is at best unproductive.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The question you link to deals with a different facet of tar. It does not address the OP's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

```
tar -zcpf /dev/null -g files.snar /path/to/folder
```

Comment: `-z` (compression) is unnecessary as you are discarding the output and wastes computing power. `-p` probably doesn't do anything when using `-c` (`--create`).